# Minimum zoom scale of one day for date axis in Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly

Is there a way to restrict the minimum zoom of plotly chart to one day?

In the `tickformat` of `xaxis`, I specified `%d %b` to show only day and month. If you zoom too much, the chart will show multiple ticks for one day.
I know `plotly` tries to zoom the axes further on the bases of time but that is not required in my case.

I have tried using `tickvals` and `ticktexts` but ended up having too many overlapping ticks as trace's x array can have values from 0 to 365 days.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07', '2000-01-08', '2000-01-09', '2000-01-10', '2000-01-11', '2000-01-12', '2000-01-13', '2000-01-14', '2000-01-15', '2000-01-16', '2000-01-17', '2000-01-18', '2000-01-19', '2000-01-20', '2000-01-21', '2000-01-22', '2000-01-23', '2000-01-24', '2000-01-25', '2000-01-26', '2000-01-27', '2000-01-28', '2000-01-29', '2000-01-30', '2000-01-31'],
  y: [4.3, 8.2, 4.1, 5.6, -3, -0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 4.1, 5, 4.6, -0.2, -8.5, -9.1, -2.7, -2.7, -17, -11.3, -5.5, -6.5, -16.9, -12, -6.1, -6.6, -7.9, -10.8, -14.8, -11, -4.4, -1.3, -1.1],
  mode: 'lines',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: '2000'
};

var data = [ trace1 ];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    type: 'date',
    title: 'January Weather',
  tickformat: '%d %b'
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Daily Mean Temperature'
  },
  title:'2000 Toronto January Weather'
};

Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

I want to have single tick for a day on maximum zoom possible. Is there a way to either restrict the zoom or to show at max one tick per day?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar question, but I only want to show months disregard if is zoom in or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the best way is to use `type: 'category'` instead `type: 'date'`